# Combinar valores en una sola fila si el valor de una columna coincide

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hola a todos quiero combinar en una sola fila, aquellos valores que tengan el mismo codigo postal. El codigo postal corresponde a una zona,Aqui ilustrare mi set de datos.

Tengo tres columnas que son: Codigo postal,Zona y Barrio
Ejemplo de dos filas

> ```
> Codigo postal    Zona   Barrio  
>           M1A   Zona1   Centro  
>           M1A   Zona1      Sur
> ```

Quiero que mi set de datos se modifique y quede de esta manera:

> ```
> Codigo Postal    Zona        Barrio  
>           M1A   Zona1    Centro,Sur
> ```

Como ven la columna `barrio` esta tomando dos valores separados por coma de esta manera "Centro,Sur" y esas dos filas se convirtieron en una

Son 300 filas que tiene mi dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente, lo que necesitas es agrupar por `Código postal` (y `Zona`) para lo cual la herramienta es `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. Una vez agrupado basta con usar el método [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) junto a `str.join` para unir la columna `Barrio` (que marca los elementos de cada grupo) con comas:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Codigo postal": ("M1A", "M1A", "M2B"),
                   "Zona": ("Zona1", "Zona1", "Zona2"),
                   "Barrio": ("Centro", "Sur", "Este")
                   })
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>   Codigo postal   Zona  Barrio
> 0           M1A  Zona1  Centro
> 1           M1A  Zona1     Sur
> 2           M2B  Zona1    Este
> ```

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Codigo postal', "Zona"])['Barrio'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

> ```
> >>> df1
>
>   Codigo postal   Zona      Barrio
> 0           M1A  Zona1  Centro,Sur
> 1           M2B  Zona1        Este
> ```